# Does a value (100) store the same amount of memory as another value (10000000)?

Tags: memory

So I was wondering if a smaller number holds the same amount of space as a number bigger than it, assuming they are both ints. Also which number would be faster to retrieve from memory or would they both be retrieved at the same speed?

edit: Assume language is c and type is int.

Comment: This depends entirely on the language, the number type used, and I'd think the architecture the program is running on.

Comment: Assuming a 32-bit-architecture machine, `int` storage will be 32 bits, so any number less than 2^31 (subtract one sign bit) will use the same amount of memory (32 bits) and incur the same cost for memory access (AFAICT).

Answer (score 0):

With C <sup>(a)</sup>, the space requirements belong to the *type* rather than to the value.

Hence an `int` type will take the same space whether the value is zero or the maximum value that an `int` can be.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> And in many other languages as well, though there are notable exceptions like Python, where the basic `int` type is not arbitrarily limited in range. Or the zig-zag encoding of signed integers in Protobuf where it's both variable size *and* smaller absolute values get preferenced in terms of space consumed.